# LDAPError: (0, 'Error') and LDAPError: (2, 'No such file or directory') with flask

Tags: python, flask, ldap

I am trying to implement LDAP. I am using following as guide.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/flask-authentication-with-ldap--cms-23101.

According to comments below tutorial, I have used

> current_user.is_authenticated: rather than
>   current_user.is_authenticated():

Application started, however, I am getting following errors when I try to used login LDAP.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "home/user//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "home/user/Desktop/flask_app/my_app/auth/views.py", line 41, in login
    User.try_login(username, password)
  File "home/user/Desktop/flask_app/my_app/auth/models.py", line 22, in try_login
    conn = get_ldap_connection()
  File "home/user/Desktop/flask_app/my_app/auth/models.py", line 9, in get_ldap_connection
    conn = ldap.initialize(app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'])
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 94, in initialize
    return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 77, in __init__
    self._l = ldap.functions._ldap_function_call(ldap._ldap_module_lock,_ldap.initialize,uri)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 66, in _ldap_function_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
LDAPError: (2, 'No such file or directory')



File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "home/user/Desktop/flask_app/my_app/auth/views.py", line 41, in login
    User.try_login(username, password)
  File "home/user/Desktop/flask_app/my_app/auth/models.py", line 22, in try_login
    conn = get_ldap_connection()
  File "home/user/Desktop/flask_app/my_app/auth/models.py", line 9, in get_ldap_connection
    conn = ldap.initialize(app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'])
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 94, in initialize
    return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 77, in __init__
    self._l = ldap.functions._ldap_function_call(ldap._ldap_module_lock,_ldap.initialize,uri)
  File "home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 66, in _ldap_function_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
LDAPError: (0, 'Error')
```

My LDAP Provider URL I have used alternatively following two option

```
app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'] = 'xxx.xxxx.net/CN=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=net'
```

and

```
app.config['LDAP_PROVIDER_URL'] = 'xxx.xxxx.net
```

However, I am not able to get answer. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you have not mentioned, that i have to check is:

Did you add ports and such to your PROVIDER_URL?

Did you add the full format: ldap://ldap.testathon.net:389/ ?

Last, confirm that the LDAP is actually working with ldapsearch, like this:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h host.example.com -D user -w password -b"dc=ad,dc=example,dc=com" -s sub "(objectClass=user)" givenName
```

If all of these are okay, you would need to post your "flask_app/my_app/**init**.py".

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem. I managed to solve it like this:

I changed this

```
connect = ldap.initialize("x.x.x.x")
```

to this

```
connect = ldap.initialize("ldap://x.x.x.x")
```