# LDAP (2, 'No such file or directory') error using DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, ldap, ldap-query

I am implementing a Django app, I am trying to fetch data from an LDAP server.
Here is my code in views.py.I have supplied all the necessary information below, but yet I am facing (2, 'No such file or directory') error. What Am I missing here?

```
                LDAP_USERNAME = ""
                LDAP_PASSWORD = ""
                LDAP_BASEDN = ""
                try:
                    l = ldap.initialize('')
                    l.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION2
                    l.simple_bind_s(LDAP_USERNAME, LDAP_PASSWORD)
                    search_filter = "(cn=*)"
                    search_attribute = None
                    search_scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
                    ldap_result_id = l.search(LDAP_BASEDN, search_scope, search_filter, search_attribute)
                    result_set = []
                    while 1:
                        result_type, result_data = l.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
                        if (result_data == []):
                            break
                        else:
                            if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
                                result_set.append(result_data)
                    print result_set
                except ldap.LDAPError, e:
                    print e
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/////views.py", line 43, in index
    l = ldap.initialize('xyz')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 94, in initialize
    return LDAPObject(uri,trace_level,trace_file,trace_stack_limit)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._l = ldap.functions._ldap_function_call(ldap._ldap_module_lock,_ldap.initialize,uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 66, in _ldap_function_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
LDAPError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

Comment: can you add the `error stack trace`?

Comment: So this is what can't be found: `"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ldap/functions.py"`. It's not installed or there's a problem with your path, etc...

Comment: I don't know for some reason, I am able to connect to the server using ldap.open (facing the above error when using ldap.initialize ) which is deprecated. Answer to this question is still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`ldap.initialize()` requires a proper URL for the LDAP source. I had a same issue and [LDAPError: (0, 'Error') and LDAPError: (2, 'No such file or directory') with flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594471/ldaperror-0-error-and-ldaperror-2-no-such-file-or-directory-with-fla) helped me.

Try `ldap.initialize(<protocol>://<host>:<port>)`. default `protocol` would be `ldap` and the default port is `389`.